# scope.$watch(attrs. is not working with a custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I am using scope.$watch to look for changes on an attribute-based directive.  These changes are initiated by an ng-model binding on an input element in the view. The directive *attribute* on the view is being watched using scope.$watch in the directive.  Yet the change event never seems to fire in the directive.  What is causing my code to break?

The portions highlighted in the code below, where I log to the console (in the directive code, with stars), never fire.  The change to the controller scope, via ng-model on the input, is not being propagated to the directive.

If I change the attribute value to a static string, rather than binding it via ng-model, it works.

This code is taken from a working example in the AngularJS documentation [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uCTy8Io0v8lOQ0OCCm7J?p=preview).  I cannot 'spot the difference' as the code in the documentation is very similar to mine.

```
angular.module('myApp.advancedDirectives', [
  'myApp.advancedDirectives.advancedDirectives-directive'
])


.value('data', { name: 'John', surname: 'Smith' })


angular.module('myApp.advancedDirectives.advancedDirectives-directive', [])

.directive('advancedDirectives', ['$interval', 'dateFilter', 'data', function ($interval, dateFilter, data) {
    console.log(data.length);

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var format,
            timeoutId;

        scope.$watch(attrs.advancedDirectives, function (theFormat) {
            format = theFormat;
            **console.log(theFormat);
            updateTime();**
        });

    element.on('$destroy', function () {
        $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
    });


    // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
    timeoutId = $interval(function () {
        updateTime(); // update DOM
    }, 1000);

    function updateTime() {
        scope.directiveScope2 = dateFilter(new Date(), format);
    }
}

    var theScope = {
    directiveScope1: '=info'
}

return {
    templateUrl: 'components/advancedDirectives/advancedDirectivesTemplate.html',
    scope: theScope,
    link: link
}
}]);

<div ng-controller="viewAdvancedDirectivesCtrl">
    <div>
        <div><input ng-model="theViewFormat"/></div>
        <div>Data from the directive scope: <span advanced-directives="theViewFormat" info='data'></span></div>
    </div>
</div>





<span style='background:yellow'>Advanced Directive. Here is some data: {{directiveScope1.name}} {{directiveScope1.surname}}, alive at {{directiveScope2}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using isolated scope for your directive, `theViewFormat` value wouldn't be available inside your directive context.

Either you need to use `$parent.+ attrs.advancedDirectives` while placing `$watch`

**OR**

More preferred way would be pass `advancedDirectives` via attribute to isolated scope like you did for passing `info` data

```
var theScope = {
    directiveScope1: '=info',
    advanced: '=advancedDirectives'
}
```

Then simply your watch would be on `'advanced'` string.

```
scope.$watch('advanced', function (theFormat) {
     format = theFormat;
     console.log(theFormat);
     updateTime();**
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Panjak (as well as @Anik) What you suggest is to watch the directive scope. But this leaves me with a problem, because when I update the directive scope in updateTime(), it re-fires the watch, and I am left with the wrong value.  What I want to observe/watch is the _attribute value_ so that the format of the date-time can be exposed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

Below, please see the *view* code.
Note: I used curly-braces for {{theViewFormat}}

```
<div ng-controller="viewAdvancedDirectivesCtrl">
    <div>
        <div>Data from the directive scope: <span advanced-directives="{{theViewFormat}}" info='data'></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The *link code* looks like below. 
Note: Use of $observe (as recommended by @Anik)
Note: I am observing on the attrs, rather than on the directive scope object, therefore avoiding recursive calls to updateTime, and I am now observing the attribute change, rather than the scope change, which matches my requirement.

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var format,
            timeoutId;


        attrs.$observe('advancedDirectives', function (theFormat) {
            format = theFormat;
            console.log('format changed: ' + format);
            updateTime();
        });

    element.on('$destroy', function () {
        $interval.cancel(timeoutId);
    });


    // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
    timeoutId = $interval(function () {
        updateTime(); // update DOM
    }, 1000);

    function updateTime() {
        scope.directiveScope2 = dateFilter(new Date(), format);
        console.log('updateTime: ' + format + dateFilter(new Date(), format));
    }
}
```

The *updateTime() code*, which updates the directive scope is as follows:

```
function updateTime() {
        scope.directiveScope2 = dateFilter(new Date(), format);
        console.log('updateTime: ' + format + dateFilter(new Date(), format));
    }
```

Thanks to @Pankaj and @Anik for getting me a long way ahead.